# Wrong text encoding when parsing json data

Tags: linux, json, parsing, shell, curl

I am curling a website and writing it to .json file; this file is input to my java code which parses it using json library and the necessary data is written back in a CSV file which i later use to store it in a database.

As you know data coming from a website can be in different formats so i make sure that i read and write in `UTF-8` format, still i get wrong output.

For example, `Østerriksk` becomes `ï¿½sterriksk`.

I am doing all this in Linux. I think there is some encoding problem because this same code runs fine in Windows but not in Unix/Linux.

I am quite sure my java code is proper but i am not able to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Should i change my approach to parse the json file from shell instead of having java program?if so please guide me in that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the data as ISO 8859-1 but the file is actually UTF-8. I think there's an argument (or setting) to the file reader that should solve that.

Also: curl isn't going to care about the encodings. It's really something in your Java code that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.All i had to do was read in ISO 8859-1 and write it in utf-8...That worked properly..

Answer (score 0):

What kind of IDE are you using, for example this can happen if you are using Eclipse IDE, and not set your default encoding to utf-8 in properties.